# How to draw a chart with Diagonal Arrows?

Tags: diagrams, arrows, charts

How may I create this chart? I thought that through a table it would be fine but the arrows were short and a little bit misplaced

```
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    &  &  &  &  \\ 
    &  & Finita (Se\~{n}al de Energ\'{\i}a P=0) &  &  \\ 
    & $ \nearrow $ &  &  &  \\ 
    E &  &  &  & P Finita (se\~{n}al de Potencia) \\ 
    & $ \searrow $ &  & $ \nearrow $ &  \\ 
    &  & Infinita &  &  \\ 
    &  &  & $ \searrow $ &  \\ 
    &  &  &  & P Infinta (No es SE ni SP) \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

.

[image]

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your post, replacing your original backtick syntax `like this` with "code sample" formatting. Highlight the whole code and click the "code sample" button ({}), or alternatively add four spaces before each line (the code sample button does this for you, but you can do it yourself). For a long sample of code such as yours, this is prettier and it adds syntax highlighting as well. Backticks are better for marking down individual commands/names that sort of thing, e.g. "the `tabular` environment is working"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a tree, I'd suggest you the [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  grow'=east,
  l sep=2cm,
  child anchor=west,
  parent anchor=east,
  edge={->,>=latex}}
[E
  [{Finita (Señal de energía $P=0$)},
  ]
  [Infinita, xshift=-1.8cm
    [{$P$ finita (Señal de potencia)}
    ]
    [{$P$ infinita (No es SE ni SP)}
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252737) which does not require manually adjusting the horizontal placement of one of the nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      font=\sffamily,
      grow'=0,
      anchor=west,
      child anchor=west,
      l sep+=15mm,
      edge={-{Stealth[]}},
    }
    [E
      [{Finita (Señal de energía $P=0$)}
      ]
      [Infinita
        [{$P$ finita (Señal de potencia)}
        ]
        [{$P$ infinita (No es SE ni SP)}
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

If you want the branches to start from a single point, add `parent anchor=east` as well.

[image: variation]